# Filter from map - dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to scan and filter a collection from dynamodb which looks like,

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "car_type_id": 1,
  "car_performance": {
    "question": [
      {
        "answer": false,
        "answer_type": "BO",
        "question_id": 1
      },
      {
        "answer": 402.3,
        "answer_type": "FL",
        "question_id": 2
      },
      {
        "answer": "2019-07-17 10:44:04",
        "answer_type": "DT",
        "question_id": 3
      }
    ],
    "engine": {
      "is_active": true,
      "total_score": 65.4
    },
    "acceleration": {
      "is_active": true,
      "total_score": 77
    },
    "hydraulics": {
      "is_active": true,
      "total_score": 45
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get all the list that have `car_type_id == 1` and `engine.total_score between 50 to 80` and contains **question** with id 2 and 3

I have the query like,

```
engine =  {
      "is_active": true,
      "total_score": 65.4
    }
table = dynamodb.Table('CarDetails')
response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('job_stage_id').eq(1) & (Attr('engine').conatins(engine))
)
```

I dont get how to apply range condidtion along with others. 
id it possible to apply a query like ,

```
select * from CarDetails where car_performance.engine.total_score between 50 and 80 and car_type_id = 1 car_performance.questions.question_id contains  [2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `between()` method to do that :

```
FilterExpression=Attr('job_stage_id').eq(1) & 
    (Attr('engine').contains(engine)) & (Attr('total_score').between(50, 80))
```

The documentation for possible conditions is available here : 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/conditions.html